# change font size of text on UIImage with image's dimension in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I need to display text on UIImage which I am able to achieve with following code.

```
+(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text :(UIImage*) image :(CGPoint) point
{
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, 0.0f);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x,point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);

        UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:80]; //want to increase and decrease font size as per UIImage's dimension.
    
        NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 NSFontAttributeName : font};
            [text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attrs];
    
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
}
```

but I want to change font size as per UIImage's dimension. Right now font size is static in my code.

Comment: what about using `CATextLayer *txt = [CATextLayer layer];` add to `[self.view.layer addSublayer:txt];`. Easier to handle, because you can change its properties dynamically with no need to re-calculate the UIImage. So is it important to make the text part of the image buffer?

Comment: @OlSen But How can I add layer on UIImage?

Comment: question, the other way around. Where do you add your UIImage? inside a UIView that has a CALayer by default (like on UIKit/ios) ?

Comment: @OlSen I choose image from camera or photoLibrary and I save that image in documentsDirectory with text on it.

Comment: ok, in that case you need the text as part of your UIImage (buffer). You just need to take out your `80` and exchange it with a little formula depending on your image.size